# Spring Boot OpenAPI 3 with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, springdoc, springdoc-ui

I'm failing at documenting my Spring Data REST API with OpenAPI. Nothing show in swagger-ui's homepage (and /v3/api-docs obviously).

Here is an excerpt from my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And there is my JPA repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonsRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
Person findByLastname(@Param("name") @RequestParam("name") String lastname);
}
```

And this my Spring Boot setup:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
#springdoc.paths-to-match=/people/**
```

Of course, my CRUD API is ok over /people PATH.
Even the /profile/people PATH seems right.

I must be missing something... Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this URL:

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#

My Configurations

I have also created this OpenAPI Bean:

```java
 @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .components(new Components())
                .info(new Info().title("Test")
                        .description("Test Description")
                        .version("1.0.0"));
    }
```

Above the RestController API Endpoint Method
,I added the following annotations

```
 @Operation(summary = "Send Messages to Ibm Mq", description = "Send Message to the related ibm mq")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success Response",
                    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = SomeClass.class), mediaType = "application/json")),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal System Error",
                    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = SomeClass.class), mediaType = "application/json")),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid Parameter Request",
                    content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = SomeClass.class), mediaType = "application/json"))
    })
```

All the imports came from
io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations package

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip! Is this documented anywhere, though? I've tried hard coding the property (springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#) but ended up with a petstore demo...

Comment: SURPRISE: after discarding the above property, the main URL (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html) finally started to show the right API documentation... I'm so confused, right now :-D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your spring boot parent is in version 3+

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

You have to use the dedicated springdoc openapi dependencies for spring data rest which are :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```